# Docker - Returning Loopback Address

Tags: azerothcore

I git-cloned the master (at commit `42a1650d3146e025d996ce5b9b5dfbd9bd8fbe88`) then ran through the documented Docker build steps, exposed the ports, etc. However, even after updating realmlist to use my DNS entry, the packet-capture still shows that it's trying to connect via the loopback.

Am I missing something here? I'm substituting my DNS entries below... but they resolve to the correct external IP and aren't in any hosts files. Port 8085 also is reachable from my test client (verified via telnet)

```
mysql> select * from realmlist\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                  id: 1
                name: BB Home
             address: boonebytes.example.internet.accessible
        localAddress: 127.0.0.1
     localSubnetMask: 255.255.255.0
                port: 8085
                icon: 0
                flag: 0
            timezone: 1
allowedSecurityLevel: 0
          population: 0
           gamebuild: 12340 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Auth Server log-tail (recognizes DNS entry):

```
Updating Auth database...
>> Auth database is up-to-date! Containing 1 new and 35 archived updates.

Started auth database connection pool.
Loading IP Location Database...

Added realm "BB Home" at boonebytes.example.internet.accessible:8085.
Ping MySQL to keep connection alive
```

World Server log-tail:

```
AzerothCore rev. unknown 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (Archived branch)
(Unix, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon) ready...
Starting up Auction House Listing thread...
Calendar deletion of old events.
AC> Update time diff: 2. Players online: 0.
Update time diff: 1. Players online: 0.
```

Wireshark screenshot attached from the Realmlist response packet, indicating the loopback is being sent to the client (accessing across the internet, no VPN). The Wireshark capture does not show any attempts by the client to connect to the server on 8085; just 3724.

[image: Wireshark screenshot, indicating the Server Socket is 127.0.0.1:8085, for BB Home]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. Posting here in case others run into the same issue. Sorry in advance for missing the commands; I had rebuilt the images a few times until I realized what had happened.

- The docker containers were asking the host for DNS lookups.
- The new CNAME entry I added externally resolved to an A record that was overridden in my internal DNS server.
- Example: "games.example.com" was a CNAME to "myserver.example.com". MyServer would resolve to an external IP if queried from the internet, but the internal DNS server resolved it to 127.0.0.1 (to keep internal traffic from hitting the internet).
- It didn't completely register with me that the server would do the DNS resolution locally and only send the IP to the client.
- Specifying the external IP in the realmlist table (instead of just the DNS record) was the trick. Alternatively, I probably could've also added a Type A DNS for "games.example.com" to resolve to the external IP as well.

Additional troubleshooting tip: Consider installing DNS utilities on the Auth Server, and run a DNS lookup directly from that container for the domain you're specifying in your realmlist.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not a docker user.
But i am almost certain that world and auth server run in different containers and can not access one another with local host 127.0.0.1.

Make sure you have adjusted the realmlist table and both world- and auth server conf files accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran `update realmlist set localaddress = 'ac-worldserver', localsubnetmask = '255.255.0.0' where id = 1;`, selected the record back to confirm, checked ping from the auth server to ac-worldserver, etc. World Server responds via ping from Auth Server. Also verified telnet to 8085; no issues. Wireshark capture still shows `Server Socket = 127.0.0.1:8085` though (even though that's not the IP; ie: `telnet ac-worldserver 8085` - `Trying 172.19.0.3...` - `Connected to ac-worldserver.
Escape character is '^]'.`

Comment: Meant to add: Also restarted the containers to ensure changes were loaded. Plus, 127.0.0.1:8085 is not in any config file, nor is it in the realmlist table anymore. Is it possible the code's falling back to that for other reasons?

Comment: I don't know how IPs are assigned to docker containers. But what you want to add to your realmlist table, is the IP which your client would need to access the worldserver. It doesn't matter how auth- and world server are related IP-wise. Auth just passes the IP to the client and it tries to connect to world using it.

Comment: In this case, the clients need the external, Internet address. I'm using a DNS record currently (which resolves on the internet to the correct IP, and I get a successful connection from the client via telnet). I think the problem is that the auth server is sending 127.0.0.1 even though that's not in the DB.

Comment: If the auth server still sends 127.0.0.1, you might have changed the default values of the `realmlist` table instead of the actual data. Which is a very common mistake, mostly for users of HeidiSQL.

Comment: Thanks! I was using the MySQL command-line; haven't tried HeidiSQL before. I think I can see that being a problem though.

FYI, I found the cause of my issue after; posted as a separate answer. Thanks for your help and patience! :)